# gulp-rsync での同期時に error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) が発生する

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gulp, rsync

gulp-rsync でファイルを同期しようとすると、以下のエラーが表示されました。

```
gulp-rsync: rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12)
```

不安定なインターネット接続や間違っている接続先の様な簡単な理由でしたら、この質問を伺いするまでではなかったので、自分の努力を報告します。
尚、接続先 (VPS) は練習用なので、IPアドレス等の情報はそのまま載せています。

```js
import Gulp from "gulp";
import GulpRSync from "gulp-rsync";

Gulp.task(
  "Deploy",
  (): NodeJS.ReadWriteStream => Gulp.src("03-ProductionBuild/BackEndEntryPoint.js").
      pipe(GulpRSync({
        root: "03-ProductionBuild/",
        hostname: "160.251.43.156",
        port: "22",
        username: "non_root_admin",
        destination: "/var/www/yamatodaiwa.com"
      }))
);
```

### 間違っている接続先原因除外

この原因の可能性があると言われたのは以下のページです。

[バックアップログにエラーが記録される場合の対処方法は | バッファロー](https://www.buffalo.jp/support/faq/detail/2633.html)

パスワードを聞かれたら、正しいパスワードを入力してみます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上記のがエラーが発生します。

```
Message:
    Error: rsync exited with code 12
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\IntelliJ IDEA\InHouseDevelopment\yamatodaiwa.com\node_modules\gulp-rsync\rsync.js:121:17)      
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:537:15)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
    at Process.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
```

今回はパスワードをわざと間違って入力してみます。
違うエラーが発生します。

```
non_root_admin@160.251.43.156's password: [18:36:47] gulp-rsync: Permission denied, please try again.
```

従って、バックエンド側は認証まで正常に動いています。念の為一般のターミナルで接続してみます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

成功でした。

### サーバー側でrsyncが入っていない原因除外

ターミナルVPSと接続し`rsync -v`で除外完了です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### サーバー側で容量が足りない原因除外

コードで同期しようとしているファイルの **BackEndEntryPoint.js** はたった92.0 KBです。VPS側のディスク使用量の情報は以下の通りです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

#### 追記

下記の実験の前にSSH接続の正常性を確認しました。

##### 通常の rsync での実行結果

```
>  rsync -a "03-ProductionBuild/BackEndEntryPoint.js" non_root_admin@160.251.43.156:/var/www/yamatodaiwa.com     
non_root_admin@160.251.43.156's password: 
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(235) [Receiver=3.1.3]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(228) [sender=3.2.3]
```

##### `-vvv` オプション付き

```
PS D:\IntelliJ IDEA\InHouseDevelopment\yamatodaiwa.com>  rsync -a "03-ProductionBuild/BackEndEntryPoint.js" non_root_admin@160.251.43.156:/var/www/yamatodaiwa.com -vvv
opening connection using: ssh -l non_root_admin 160.251.43.156 rsync --server -vvvlogDtpre.iLsfxCIvu . /var/www/yamatodaiwa.com  (9 args)
non_root_admin@160.251.43.156's password: 
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(235) [Receiver=3.1.3]
[Receiver] _exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=235): about to call exit(12)
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(228) [sender=3.2.3]
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=228): about to call exit(12)
```

Comment: rsync を実行しているのは Windows 環境のようですが、標準では rsync コマンドが使えないはずなので、どのような環境なのかも念のため記載してみてください。

Comment: @cubick, ローカルはWindows 10 ですが、rsyncの導入は可能です。導入方法は覚えておりませんが、chocolateyだったでしょう。バージョンは3.2.3です。

Comment: 接続先サーバに該当のディレクトリは間違いなく存在していますか？？/var/www/yamatodaiwa.com

Comment: @keitaro_so いいえ、存在していません。存在していなくてもファイル・フォルダー関連手段ですから、rsyncが勝手に作ってくれるかと思っておりました。

Answer (score 3):

同期に伴うファイルやフォルダの作成にも適切な権限が必要です。

コピー先に指定している `non_root_admin@160.251.43.156:/var/www/yamatodaiwa.com` ですが、
そもそも `/var/www` は一般的に root 以外のユーザーで書き込みができないようになっています。

**例:**

```
$ ls -ld /var/www
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096  1月 25 23:09 /var/www/
```

実行ユーザーの `non_root_admin` が非 root ユーザーなのであれば、以下いずれかの対応が考えられます。

- `/var/www` に 対して non_root_admin でも書き込めるようにする
- `/var/www/yamatodaiwa.com` を事前に作成して non_root_admin でも書き込めるようにする

もしくは、non_root_admin で `sudo` コマンドが許可されているなら、ローカル側での `rsync` コマンドで
`--rsync-path` オプションを使う方法が手っ取り早いかもしれません。

[rsync でリモート側の実行権限が非 root ユーザーの場合、ファイルの所有者情報がコピーされない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/86551)

> ```
> # rsync --rsync-path="sudo rsync" -auvz /path/to/SOURCE ec2-user@REMOTE:/path/to/TARGET
> ```

Comment: 御解答に感謝致します。せっかく手伝ってくださいましたのに、未だエラーが消えていなくて誠に申し訳ございません。VPSで`sudo mkdir yamatodaiwa.com -m755`で **var/www/yamatodaiwa.com**を用意致しました。**www** で`ls -la`を実行しますと、`drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096`が表示されます。此の段階までは、異常が御座いませんでしょうか？

Comment: パーミッションが 755 (rwxr-xr-x) だと所有者以外に書き込み権限がありません。

Comment: この場合は十分でないという理解で宜しいでしょうか？777は危険すぎるそうですが、、、

Comment: ですので、回答中にも "sudo が使えるなら `--rsync-path` オプションを使う方法" を紹介しています。

Comment: コンソルに直接打ち込むといけるとしても、目標は**gulp-rsync**でデプロイする事です。然し、実験の為に`rsync --rsync-path="sudo rsync" -auvz "D:\IntelliJ IDEA\InHouseDevelopment\yamatodaiwa.com\03-ProductionBuild\BackEndEntryPoint.js" non_root_admin@160.251.43.156:/var/www/yamatodaiwa.com`の実行を試しました。結果は`The source and destination cannot both be remote. rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1420)`というエラーです。

Comment: 実験の為に改めて777権限を付けてyamatodaiwa.comディレクトリを作成してみました。本当に申し訳ない気持ちが強いですか、エラーが消えていません。本当に誰かに有料支援でも頼みたいですが、StackOveflow上規則違反でしょう、、、

Comment: まずエラーメッセージを読みましょう。転送元のファイルは元々相対パスで指定していたのに、絶対パスでドライブ文字が入ったことで転送元もリモートホストとして誤認識されているように見えます。 / パーミッションの問題を切り分けるなら、転送先のディレクトリに `/tmp` を指定して実行してみてください。