# rsync でリモート側の実行権限が非 root ユーザーの場合、ファイルの所有者情報がコピーされない

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, rsync

rsync を使ってサーバ間でファイルを同期しようとしています。

実行ユーザーがローカルは root ですが、リモート側は Amazon EC2 の環境で ec2-user (一般ユーザー) となっており、rsync コマンドのオプションに `-a` (アーカイブモード) を指定しているにも関わらず、コピーしたファイルの所有者がすべて ec2-user になってしまいます。

元の権限 (所有者情報) を維持したままコピーするにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

**現状の実行例:**

```
# rsync -auvz /path/to/SOURCE ec2-user@REMOTE:/path/to/TARGET
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rsync のオプション `--rsync-path` で rsync コマンドを `sudo` 経由で呼び出すことで解決しました。

**実行例:**

```
# rsync --rsync-path="sudo rsync" -auvz /path/to/SOURCE ec2-user@REMOTE:/path/to/TARGET
```

**参考にしたページ:**
[リモートでsudoしてrsyncしたい](https://mattintosh.hatenablog.com/entry/20200325/1585115330)